# Angular: How to dynamically load a component defined by a string?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-components

How do I compile a component defined by a string and render it in my template?

I tried using [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer):

```js
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(parsedLinksString);
```

But that doesn't properly bind the `click` event handler `onButtonClick()`.

#### Desired Functionality

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-sample-component',
    templateUrl: './sample-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sample-component.component.scss']
})
export class SampleComponent {

  buildMessage() {
    // How do I parse this string and render so that it responds to events?
    const myOutput = '<button (click)="onButtonClick()';
  }

  onButtonClick() {
    console.log('Handler for Dynamic Button');
  }

}
```

Comment: are you using the `innerHTML` attribute on the parent DOM element to the rendered string? from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48914307/5927442)

Comment: This strikes me as an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/193656). People may be able to better assist you if you ask about what outcome or functionality you are trying to obtain. What is the reason for trying to create a button like this via an HTML string?

Comment: Yes, I tried using the innerHtml attribute and render it, however (click) events does not work as it's pure HTML and does not understand Angular bindings.

Comment: How would you develop the following component?

A Notification Component, that is connects to a store, and any component can call an action and displays notifications. However, these notification texts may contain a call to action link (like, click here for more). This link is a dynamic content and also have to bind to a method/event in an Angular class

Comment: If only want a button, check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71479471/execute-angular-innerhtml-as-normal-angular-code/71480844#71480844)

Answer (score 1):

The Angular security model is designed such that HTML added to `[innerHTML]="myOutput"` is not processed (i.e. scripts are not executed and events are not triggered).

Angular options to compile HTML include:

## Add HTML to a Component Template

In your example, the HTML would go in `sample-component.component.html`. To dynamically include or exclude HTML in a template, use [structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) such as `*ngIf` and `*ngFor`.

## Create a Dynamic Component to load at Runtime

See [**Dynamic Component Loader**](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

<kbd>[**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so58087736-ng-dynamic-component?file=src/app/app.component.ts)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-86uxvs?file=src/app/app.component.html

I did [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71427012/angular-13-how-to-compile-component-at-run-time) and the solution was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71071707/dynamically-add-mattooltip-in-text-for-specific-keywords/71072868#71072868) made by [@cris hamilton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12914833/chris-hamilton).