# dynamically created mat-checkbox not correctly rendered

Tags: angular, angular-material

I create `<mat-checkbox>` elements dynamically from incoming data that fetched by API.

component.ts:

```
this.content = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<mat-checkbox>test</mat-checkbox>`)
```

component.html

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

but the checkbox input is not rendered, the same issue occures if I used `<input type="checkbox">` instead of `

and it rendered correctly if I added `<mat-checkbox` statically to component.html

please check this repo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8heckn

**note:**

`this.content` is a string, not an object. because I want to add extra spaces (tabs) before each child input.

for instance:

- programming

  - front-end

    - Angular
    - React
    - Vue
  - back-end

    - node.js
    - express.js
    - php

Answer (score 0):

"Angular doesn't process HTML added dynamically, it just adds it verbatim except some sanitization to prevent security issues." [*see Stackoverflow question* [**How to dynamically add innerHTML with angular 2 components**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40473910/1164465)]

To learn about adding Angular components dynamically, see the following:

- [**Dynamically ADDING and REMOVING Components in Angular**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44939878/1164465)
- [**Angular2: Insert a dynamic component as child of a container in the DOM**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38093727/1164465)
- [**Angular: How to dynamically load a component defined by a string?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58087736/1164465)

Comment: but I have some data (object) not a component, whitch I want to inject them inside the current component. @Christopher Peisert