# Dynamically add matTooltip in text for specific keywords

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am working in a personal Angular project (using Angular Material) and I can't find a solution for this problem.

For example, I have a long text like this :

> When you take the Dodge action, you focus entirely on avoiding
> attacks. Until the start of your next turn, any Attack roll made
> against you has **disadvantage** if you can see the attacker, and you make
> Dexterity Saving Throws with **advantage**. You lose this benefit if you
> are **Incapacitated** (as explained in Conditions ) or if your speed drops
> to 0.

I have some keywords, here disadvantage, advantage incapacitated. I would like to make the font bold and add a tooltip to add a small explanation for each keyword.

I have no problem making the font bold with a pipe, but I can't find a solution for adding a tooltip for the keywords. Using innerHTML does not work, here is my current solution :

```
<div innerHTML="description | transformKeyWord"></div>
```

And my pipe :

```
transform(value: string, ...args: unknown[]): unknown {
    let result = value
      result = result.replace('advantage', '<span matTooltip="Advantage description">advantage</span>')
      result = result.replace('incapacitated', '<b [matTooltip]="Incapacitated description">incapacitated</b>')
    return result;
  }
```

I don't think this is the good solution using a pipe with innerHTML, that is why I am asking for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-86uxvs?file=src/app/app.component.html

The way I see it, each keyword is an `object` with a `word` and a `tooltip`. So I'll define the schema for that.

```js
export type keyword = {
  word: string;
  tooltip: string;
};
```

I'll define the keywords in an object for easy lookup:

```js
  keywords: { [key: string]: keyword } = {
    disadvantage: {
      word: 'disadvantage',
      tooltip: 'advantage description',
    },
    incapacitated: {
      word: 'incapacitated',
      tooltip: 'incapacitated description',
    },
  };
```

I think the best way is to split the string into an array of strings and keywords, so we can print them to the html in order. Here's a function that does that - I put all this in a service because it seems fitting.

```js
  toDynamicText(text: string): (string | keyword)[] {
    const res: (string | keyword)[] = [];
    const tokens = text.split(' ');
    let i = 0;
    for (const token of tokens) {
      let keyword = this.keywords[token.toLowerCase()]; //undefined if word is not a keyword
      if (keyword) {
        i = res.push(keyword);
      } else {
        if (!res[i]) res[i] = token;
        else res[i] += ' ' + token;
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
```

output array looks like this:

```json
[
  "When you take the Dodge action, you focus entirely on avoiding attacks. Until the start of your next turn, any Attack roll made against you has",
  {
    "word": "disadvantage",
    "tooltip": "advantage description"
  },
  "if you can see the attacker, and you make Dexterity Saving Throws with advantage. You lose this benefit if you are",
  {
    "word": "incapacitated",
    "tooltip": "incapacitated description"
  },
  "(as explained in Conditions ) or if your speed drops to 0. "
]
```

and here's an example of how to use it:

```js
  text =
    'When you take the Dodge action, you focus entirely on avoiding attacks. ' +
    'Until the start of your next turn, any Attack roll made against you has disadvantage if you can see the attacker, ' +
    'and you make Dexterity Saving Throws with advantage. ' +
    'You lose this benefit if you are Incapacitated (as explained in Conditions ) or if your speed drops to 0. ';

  dynamicText: (string | keyword)[] = [];

  constructor(private dynamicTextService: DynamicTextService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dynamicText = this.dynamicTextService.toDynamicText(this.text);
  }

  isString(token: any) {
    return typeof token === 'string';
  }
  
  //Typescript compiler wants a typecast, so we have two helper functions
  getTooltip(token: string | keyword) {
    return (token as keyword).tooltip;
  }

  getWord(token: string | keyword) {
    return (token as keyword).word;
  }
```

```html
<p>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let token of dynamicText">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isString(token)">{{ token }}</ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!isString(token)"
      ><b [matTooltip]="getTooltip(token)" style="cursor: pointer">
        {{ getWord(token) }}
      </b></ng-container
    >
  </ng-container>
</p>
```

You could make it more robust by ensuring that the `tooltip` and `word` properties exist before trying to return them.

I would make this a component with `text` as an input variable.

Comment: Great solution ! Thank you !

Comment: Help me too.  Thank you. Congratulations to @Eliseo that show me your solution! Long Live to SOF community!