# display decode html in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, base64, html-encode

Im doing payment gateway, after user click `proceed`, I send required data and getting from the back-end an `base64` encode string contain `html` to redirect to payment gateway page.

this is what I had tried:

```
base64 : PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+PGgxPk15IEZpcnN0IEhlYWRpbmc8L2gxPjxwPk15IGZpcnN0IHBhcmFncmFwaC48L3A+PC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4=
```

after I decode in my ts file using :

```
const decodeHtml = window.atob(this.base64);
```

I got  result like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>
```

How I can display this `html` on my project, binding to html file or pointing out to new url ?
based on my finding, i can use `innerHtml` to bind this, but I am not sure if there are better practice to doing this and got non idea how to display this encode `html` file, any suggestion are welcomed.

Comment: The best practice is not to do it at all. Angular isn't made to do such things. And using `innerHTML` would still be a bad practice because you would have two doctypes.

Comment: This might help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913344/angular-5-adding-html-content-dynamically